# how to consume meteor API call

Tags: api, meteor

I need to write a Java web application to call a function Meteor APP. One way is through API call. Are there any other means to call Meteor function from 3rd party application.

Thanks
Murali

Comment: You can call meteor methods via `DDP` protocol. Didn't use, but there are DPP Java clients.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what your requirements are, how your Meteor app is structured, and what sort of integration you desire.

If you are wanting your Java web application to be able to natively call Meteor methods or subscribe to publications, then you will have to use a Java DDP Client to do this.  Fortunately, there is at least one documented [Java DDP client](https://github.com/kenyee/java-ddp-client) that you can use for this (and probably many others out there is you search).  For your reference, here is a [compiled list](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients) of DDP clients for other languages/technologies.

If on the other hand you don't want to interface with you meteor app using DDP, then you could always implement a REST API in your meteor app.  There are several packages available to do this, but I would highly recommend the [`simple:rest`](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest) package.

This package automatically creates a REST API for all your existing publications and methods without any extra code (just simply add the package to your meteor app).  If you do need to configure or modify the REST API, the package also provides several options that you can use in your publication or meteor method definition.  The package also enforces all your app's security rules and authorization.

For example, if your app had a publication called `openTasks`, then the corresponding REST endpoint would be.

```
GET /publications/openTasks
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few packages at https://atmospherejs.com/?q=rest that can expose your Meteor methods as RESTful API points which your Java app can consume.